# problemas com consulta via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Não consigo retornas os dados do meu php para o js usando ajax, fiz o seguinte:

```
<?php
        
header('Content-Type: application/json');

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

$master = ["numero" => $i];
echo json_encode($master);

}
```

no js ficou assim

```
}).done(function (result) {

    console.log(result)

    
  });
```

Porém, só funciona se `echo json_encode($master);` estiver fora do laço.

como posso resolver isso, ou oque devo estudar pra corrigir esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

O echo precisa estar fora do laço porque você precisa imprimir um único objeto json, não vários (como ocorre com echo dentro do laço).

O problema do seu laço é que você cria e sobrescreve `$master` a cada passo. Precisa ter um único `$master`, e imprimir só no final:

```
<?php
        
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$master = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $master[] = ["numero" => $i];
}

echo json_encode($master);
```